# Typescript interface for chrome extension manifest file

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to programmatically generate the manifest.json file for several chrome extensions.

Since I am writing the chrome extensions in typescript, and thus would like to generate the manifest.json via typescript, wanted to see if there is a typescript interface or class for the chrome manifest.json ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but posting this here in case anyone else (like myself) stumbles across it.

The Definitely Typed `@types/chrome` package provides an interface for the `manifest.json` format, for both manifest version 2 and 3.

```
npm install -D @types/chrome
```

The interfaces are located in the `chrome.runtime` namespace.

```js
const manifest_v3: chrome.runtime.ManifestV3 = { /*...*/ };
const manifest_v2: chrome.runtime.ManifestV2 = { /*...*/ };
```